# VS2015 Default Site locked text boxes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webforms

I have an unusual issue.. I wanted to explore and create a website based on the Default website application.

I've added additional fields to the database like address etc using the package manager [Customizing profile information in ASP identity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/)

I confirmed the columns have been added in the database, great. Well, I added the textboxes into the form and ran the website, and all the textboxes I added are locked, can't type into them they're behaving like they're read only. Only the text boxes that came with the default website allow for input.

I viewed the properties pane and found there is absolutely no difference between the text boxes I created, and the text boxes that came with the default site.

Additionally, I tried to enable the textboxes by using Enabled="true", this didn't work.

I tried to disable all the javascript on the website from the master to see if that was interfering with my form but VS screams at me.

There is nothing in the designer that seems off they're just simple 1 liner bits of code defining the control class.

Nothing in code behind thats wonky disabling any controls.

I have never had this issue in the past with previous default websites in visual studio, I was wondering if anyone might have run into this issue and what you've done to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need to add - yes.. I have runat="server" on the <asp:TextBox>

Comment: So, I figured out how to make the text boxes enabled again. For whatever reason, if the textbox is not 100% of the width of the form, the text box disabled. I had 4 new text boxes added and they were using col-md-6 instead of col-md-12. I'm keeping this question open because I'd still like to know how CSS disables the textbox control.. thats just assanine